# What data type should I use for tuple in Spark Dataframe udf?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Input:

```
val df = Seq((10, (35, 25))).toDF("id", "scorePair")
df.show
+---+---------+
| id|scorePair|
+---+---------+
| 10| [35, 25]|
+---+---------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+-----------+
| id|totalScore |
+---+-----------+
| 10|         60|
+---+-----------+
```

Wanted to do something like this, but it does not accept **Row** type:

```
// error
val add = udf((row: Row) => {row match {case (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b}})
df.withColumn("totalScore", add(col("scorePair")))
```

Why **Row** type is not correct thinking of

> "Dataframe is an alias for Dataset[Row]"

?

What type should I use? How can I achieve it?

---

- I emphasize on the type **Row**, because at lest I manage to use **Row** in the following way (which treats each cell of a column as a **Row**) to achieve:

```
val add = udf((rows: Seq[Row]) => {rows.map {case Row(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b}})
df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("scorePair") as "pairSeq").withColumn("totalScore1", add(col("pairSeq"))).select(col("id"), explode(col("totalScore1")) as "totalScore").show
+---+----------+
| id|totalScore|
+---+----------+
| 10|        60|
+---+----------+
```

But that's really not clean!

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the attempt I tried! If i change from `val add = udf((row: Row) => {row match {case (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b}})` to `val add = udf((row: Row) => {row match {case Row(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b}})`, it should be correct. And this also answer the question about **Row** type, so yes it is Row type, everything is consistent. So i'm considering to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `row.getAs[Int](0)`, `row.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int]`, `row.getInt(0)`to get the value from row

```
val df = Seq(
  (10, (35, 25))
).toDF("id", "scorePair")


val add = udf((row: Row) => {row.getInt(0) + row.getInt(1)})

df.withColumn("totalScore", add($"scorePair")).show(false)

df.select($"id", $"scorePair._1" + $"scorePair._2" as "totalScore").show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+
|id |totalScore|
+---+----------+
|10 |60        |
+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The `aggregate` function is the easiest way to sum all the numbers in an ArrayType column.  [This post](https://mungingdata.com/spark-3/array-exists-forall-transform-aggregate-zip_with/) has a full example.  Here's the snippet:

```scala
val resDF = df.withColumn(
  "totalScore",
  aggregate(
    col("scorePair"),
    lit(0),
    (col1: Column, col2: Column) => col1 + col2
  )
)
```

You want to avoid UDFs whenever possible.  This solution only works for Spark 3+.

Comment: But the `scorePair` is of type struct as per the data provided.